# MySQL Running Total in JSON Output

Tags: mysql, json, cumulative-sum

Have been looking at this for ages, but cannot overcome the problem. Have found running total questions, but none deal with 2 queries...

```
  $query = "SELECT d.DateAdded, @running_sum:=@running_sum + d.count AS running FROM (SELECT DateAdded, COUNT(*) AS 'count' FROM details WHERE MemberStatus = 'Active'GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(DateAdded,'%Y-%m-%d') ORDER BY DateAdded ) d JOIN (SELECT @running_sum := 0 AS dummy) dummy;";
  $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);

  $array = array();

  while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
      $RunningTotal = $row2['running'];

   foreach($mysqli->query('SELECT DateAdded, COUNT(*) FROM details GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(DateAdded,"%Y-%m-%d")') as $row) {  
        $year = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($row['DateAdded']));
        array_push($array,array('Year'=>$year, 'Numb'=>$row['COUNT(*)'],'Total'=>$RunningTotal));
        } 
    }


echo json_encode($array);
```

Above is the closest I've come, but cannot get the output correct..

Current output of above is.. (obviously I have WHILE and FOREACH completely wrong!!)

```
        [{"Year":"2016-10-27","Numb":"1","Total":"1
        "},{"Year":"2016-10-31","Numb":"1","Total":"1
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-02","Numb":"1","Total":"1
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-05","Numb":"1","Total":"1
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-07","Numb":"1","Total":"1
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-08","Numb":"1","Total":"1
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-09","Numb":"1","Total":"1
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-10","Numb":"2","Total":"1
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-16","Numb":"2","Total":"1
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-20","Numb":"1","Total":"1
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-22","Numb":"1","Total":"1
        "},{"Year":"2016-12-05","Numb":"1","Total":"1
        "},{"Year":"2016-12-06","Numb":"1","Total":"1
        "},{"Year":"2016-12-07","Numb":"1","Total":"1
        "},{"Year":"2016-10-27","Numb":"1","Total":"2
        "},{"Year":"2016-10-31","Numb":"1","Total":"2
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-02","Numb":"1","Total":"2
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-05","Numb":"1","Total":"2
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-07","Numb":"1","Total":"2
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-08","Numb":"1","Total":"2
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-09","Numb":"1","Total":"2
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-10","Numb":"2","Total":"2
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-16","Numb":"2","Total":"2
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-20","Numb":"1","Total":"2
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-22","Numb":"1","Total":"2
        "},{"Year":"2016-12-05","Numb":"1","Total":"2
        "},{"Year":"2016-12-06","Numb":"1","Total":"2
        "},{"Year":"2016-12-07","Numb":"1","Total":"2
        "},{"Year":"2016-10-27","Numb":"1","Total":"3
        "},{"Year":"2016-10-31","Numb":"1","Total":"3
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-02","Numb":"1","Total":"3
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-05","Numb":"1","Total":"3
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-07","Numb":"1","Total":"3
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-08","Numb":"1","Total":"3
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-09","Numb":"1","Total":"3
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-10","Numb":"2","Total":"3
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-16","Numb":"2","Total":"3
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-20","Numb":"1","Total":"3
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-22","Numb":"1","Total":"3
        "},{"Year":"2016-12-05","Numb":"1","Total":"3
        "},{"Year":"2016-12-06","Numb":"1","Total":"3
        "},{"Year":"2016-12-07","Numb":"1","Total":"3
        "},{"Year":"2016-10-27","Numb":"1","Total":"4
        "},{"Year":"2016-10-31","Numb":"1","Total":"4
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-02","Numb":"1","Total":"4
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-05","Numb":"1","Total":"4
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-07","Numb":"1","Total":"4
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-08","Numb":"1","Total":"4
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-09","Numb":"1","Total":"4
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-10","Numb":"2","Total":"4
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-16","Numb":"2","Total":"4
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-20","Numb":"1","Total":"4
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-22","Numb":"1","Total":"4
        "},{"Year":"2016-12-05","Numb":"1","Total":"4
        "},{"Year":"2016-12-06","Numb":"1","Total":"4
        "},{"Year":"2016-12-07","Numb":"1","Total":"4
        "},{"Year":"2016-10-27","Numb":"1","Total":"5
        "},{"Year":"2016-10-31","Numb":"1","Total":"5
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-02","Numb":"1","Total":"5
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-05","Numb":"1","Total":"5
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-07","Numb":"1","Total":"5
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-08","Numb":"1","Total":"5
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-09","Numb":"1","Total":"5
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-10","Numb":"2","Total":"5
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-16","Numb":"2","Total":"5
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-20","Numb":"1","Total":"5
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-22","Numb":"1","Total":"5
        "},{"Year":"2016-12-05","Numb":"1","Total":"5
        "},{"Year":"2016-12-06","Numb":"1","Total":"5
        "},{"Year":"2016-12-07","Numb":"1","Total":"5
        "},{"Year":"2016-10-27","Numb":"1","Total":"6
        "},{"Year":"2016-10-31","Numb":"1","Total":"6
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-02","Numb":"1","Total":"6
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-05","Numb":"1","Total":"6
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-07","Numb":"1","Total":"6
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-08","Numb":"1","Total":"6
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-09","Numb":"1","Total":"6
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-10","Numb":"2","Total":"6
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-16","Numb":"2","Total":"6
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-20","Numb":"1","Total":"6
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-22","Numb":"1","Total":"6
        "},{"Year":"2016-12-05","Numb":"1","Total":"6
        "},{"Year":"2016-12-06","Numb":"1","Total":"6
        "},{"Year":"2016-12-07","Numb":"1","Total":"6
        "},{"Year":"2016-10-27","Numb":"1","Total":"7
        "},{"Year":"2016-10-31","Numb":"1","Total":"7
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-02","Numb":"1","Total":"7
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-05","Numb":"1","Total":"7
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-07","Numb":"1","Total":"7
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-08","Numb":"1","Total":"7
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-09","Numb":"1","Total":"7
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-10","Numb":"2","Total":"7
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-16","Numb":"2","Total":"7
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-20","Numb":"1","Total":"7
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-22","Numb":"1","Total":"7
        "},{"Year":"2016-12-05","Numb":"1","Total":"7
        "},{"Year":"2016-12-06","Numb":"1","Total":"7
        "},{"Year":"2016-12-07","Numb":"1","Total":"7
        "},{"Year":"2016-10-27","Numb":"1","Total":"9
        "},{"Year":"2016-10-31","Numb":"1","Total":"9
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-02","Numb":"1","Total":"9
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-05","Numb":"1","Total":"9
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-07","Numb":"1","Total":"9
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-08","Numb":"1","Total":"9
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-09","Numb":"1","Total":"9
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-10","Numb":"2","Total":"9
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-16","Numb":"2","Total":"9
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-20","Numb":"1","Total":"9
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-22","Numb":"1","Total":"9
        "},{"Year":"2016-12-05","Numb":"1","Total":"9
        "},{"Year":"2016-12-06","Numb":"1","Total":"9
        "},{"Year":"2016-12-07","Numb":"1","Total":"9
        "},{"Year":"2016-10-27","Numb":"1","Total":"11
        "},{"Year":"2016-10-31","Numb":"1","Total":"11
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-02","Numb":"1","Total":"11
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-05","Numb":"1","Total":"11
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-07","Numb":"1","Total":"11
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-08","Numb":"1","Total":"11
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-09","Numb":"1","Total":"11
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-10","Numb":"2","Total":"11
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-16","Numb":"2","Total":"11
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-20","Numb":"1","Total":"11
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-22","Numb":"1","Total":"11
        "},{"Year":"2016-12-05","Numb":"1","Total":"11
        "},{"Year":"2016-12-06","Numb":"1","Total":"11
        "},{"Year":"2016-12-07","Numb":"1","Total":"11
        "},{"Year":"2016-10-27","Numb":"1","Total":"12
        "},{"Year":"2016-10-31","Numb":"1","Total":"12
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-02","Numb":"1","Total":"12
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-05","Numb":"1","Total":"12
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-07","Numb":"1","Total":"12
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-08","Numb":"1","Total":"12
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-09","Numb":"1","Total":"12
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-10","Numb":"2","Total":"12
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-16","Numb":"2","Total":"12
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-20","Numb":"1","Total":"12
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-22","Numb":"1","Total":"12
        "},{"Year":"2016-12-05","Numb":"1","Total":"12
        "},{"Year":"2016-12-06","Numb":"1","Total":"12
        "},{"Year":"2016-12-07","Numb":"1","Total":"12
        "},{"Year":"2016-10-27","Numb":"1","Total":"13
        "},{"Year":"2016-10-31","Numb":"1","Total":"13
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-02","Numb":"1","Total":"13
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-05","Numb":"1","Total":"13
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-07","Numb":"1","Total":"13
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-08","Numb":"1","Total":"13
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-09","Numb":"1","Total":"13
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-10","Numb":"2","Total":"13
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-16","Numb":"2","Total":"13
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-20","Numb":"1","Total":"13
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-22","Numb":"1","Total":"13
        "},{"Year":"2016-12-05","Numb":"1","Total":"13
        "},{"Year":"2016-12-06","Numb":"1","Total":"13
        "},{"Year":"2016-12-07","Numb":"1","Total":"13
        "},{"Year":"2016-10-27","Numb":"1","Total":"14
        "},{"Year":"2016-10-31","Numb":"1","Total":"14
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-02","Numb":"1","Total":"14
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-05","Numb":"1","Total":"14
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-07","Numb":"1","Total":"14
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-08","Numb":"1","Total":"14
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-09","Numb":"1","Total":"14
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-10","Numb":"2","Total":"14
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-16","Numb":"2","Total":"14
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-20","Numb":"1","Total":"14
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-22","Numb":"1","Total":"14
        "},{"Year":"2016-12-05","Numb":"1","Total":"14
        "},{"Year":"2016-12-06","Numb":"1","Total":"14
        "},{"Year":"2016-12-07","Numb":"1","Total":"14
        "},{"Year":"2016-10-27","Numb":"1","Total":"15
        "},{"Year":"2016-10-31","Numb":"1","Total":"15
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-02","Numb":"1","Total":"15
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-05","Numb":"1","Total":"15
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-07","Numb":"1","Total":"15
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-08","Numb":"1","Total":"15
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-09","Numb":"1","Total":"15
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-10","Numb":"2","Total":"15
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-16","Numb":"2","Total":"15
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-20","Numb":"1","Total":"15
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-22","Numb":"1","Total":"15
        "},{"Year":"2016-12-05","Numb":"1","Total":"15
        "},{"Year":"2016-12-06","Numb":"1","Total":"15
        "},{"Year":"2016-12-07","Numb":"1","Total":"15
        "},{"Year":"2016-10-27","Numb":"1","Total":"16
        "},{"Year":"2016-10-31","Numb":"1","Total":"16
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-02","Numb":"1","Total":"16
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-05","Numb":"1","Total":"16
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-07","Numb":"1","Total":"16
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-08","Numb":"1","Total":"16
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-09","Numb":"1","Total":"16
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-10","Numb":"2","Total":"16
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-16","Numb":"2","Total":"16
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-20","Numb":"1","Total":"16
        "},{"Year":"2016-11-22","Numb":"1","Total":"16
        "},{"Year":"2016-12-05","Numb":"1","Total":"16
        "},{"Year":"2016-12-06","Numb":"1","Total":"16
        "},{"Year":"2016-12-07","Numb":"1","Total":"16
        "}]
```

Year: Date Member Added

Numb: How many signed up on that particular date

Total: Running total of new signups

Below is what it should look like.. (just tided up formatting)

```
        [{"Year":"2016-10-27","Numb":"1","Total":"1"},
        {"Year":"2016-10-27","Numb":"1","Total":"2"},
        {"Year":"2016-11-02","Numb":"1","Total":"3"},
        {"Year":"2016-11-05","Numb":"1","Total":"4"},
        {"Year":"2016-11-07","Numb":"1","Total":"5"},
        {"Year":"2016-11-08","Numb":"1","Total":"6"},
        {"Year":"2016-11-09","Numb":"1","Total":"7"},
        {"Year":"2016-11-10","Numb":"2","Total":"9"},
        {"Year":"2016-11-16","Numb":"2","Total":"11"},
        {"Year":"2016-11-20","Numb":"1","Total":"12"},
        {"Year":"2016-11-22","Numb":"1","Total":"13"},
        {"Year":"2016-12-05","Numb":"1","Total":"14"},
        {"Year":"2016-12-06","Numb":"1","Total":"15"},
        {"Year":"2016-12-07","Numb":"1","Total":"16"}]
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  This query is beyond my me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Helps if you Google the right Question... Just combined two into one.... 
;-(

```
$myArray = array();

if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DateAdded, '%Y-%m-%d') AS Year, COUNT(*) AS Numb, @running_sum:=@running_sum + d.count AS Total FROM (SELECT DateAdded, COUNT(*) AS 'count' FROM details WHERE MemberStatus = 'Active' AND PaymentStatus NOT REGEXP 'Not' GROUP BY DateAdded ORDER BY DateAdded) d JOIN (SELECT @running_sum := 0 AS dummy) dummy GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(DateAdded,'%Y-%m-%d');"))   {
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
           $myArray[] = $row;
    }
echo json_encode($myArray);
}
```